# SublimeText remove autocomplete trigger

Tags: autocomplete, triggers, sublimetext3

I'm trying to remove ; as a trigger for auto-completing in Sublime. I'm not sure which package I added that plugged this trigger in but now everytime I try to end a line, it triggers autocomplete. Argh. How to I just turn that one trigger off?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this trigger is added by [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel). I was having the same problem, removed that package, and it stopped happening.